# Xcode Compiler Error: "library not found for -lavutil"

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, compiler-warnings

I know this is a missing library that isn't added to the project but do not know what the library is.
I've looked far and wide and cannot find any relevant answers..

All that I've done is transferred the files to my new Mac and I got this error, now same error is on my old Mac too.

[image: Code]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Remove the l in `-lavutil` (which stands for library) and you get `AVUtil`, which according to Google is part of `FFmpeg`

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Thank you. Any idea how to import or what framework 'AVUtil' this is included in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved.

I realised that I still had the [Backendless](https://backendless.com) SDK files in my project. I just removed the files and the error was no more.